# youtube embed code doesn’t work on browser when i posted via form

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on small php application using codeigniter
I did just copy paste .youtube embed code on form field. it doesn’t work just show the code as it is. How so i do it ?

Comment: give us the actual code you are working with, what you want to happen, and what is currently happening.

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have xss_clean active in your $_POST which modifies $_POST variables.